# OT to ask how to contribute to open source projects?

Tags: support, specific-question

I would like to ask how I should proceed if I want to commit to an open source (e.g. Java, maybe Spring framework) project. I'm not sure if that question is OT.

I've previously used both Java and Spring in several projects. I've also done my own boilerplate code that perhaps could be useful for other developers. The goal for my boilerplate project was to create code that you can clone if you quickly want to create a new spring project. I have also other ideas how to contribute. Is it best if I try and approach the issue tracker of the project and see if I can find an issue I can help with?

I have previously contributed as a tester, a user and small change to a BSD-licenced open source project that have many users. That project is less relevant for my current specialization and I wish to commit to a relevant Java project. It's usually Spring framework that I use, I could use my change myself and hope that other developers also can use it.

Is [this link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/spr/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) right? I think it is maybe best and easiest to help with an open issue and not open a new issue that I solve myself. I created an account and try to take an issue now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a question would likely be **not on topic** here on Software Engineering.

Every project has its own culture, so it is best to ask the maintainers how you could help them. Some projects also have a document that explains how one can get involved, and where help is wanted.